# How to transfer objects from database to gui?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm playing around with entity framework and a gui trying to learn the basics but I have gotten stuck. I have created a database with the code first approach so in my Data layer, I have a db contect and DTOs for storing and retrieving data. Now this layer needs to communicate with my Buisness layer which then talks to my presentation layer. Now the question is how do I transfer data between the presentation layer and data layer? It seems to me that defining the same Model class in all three layers is stupid and cumberstone but I don't want my presentation and data layer to know about each other.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post some code for help, also you are right about sharing of Models between different layers.

Comment: I did try to implement a "shared" DLL that all projects reference, still feels a bit stupid.

Comment: For such a simple application I would use one shared library of classes. Your architecture choice should reflect the size and complexity if the system. Research Transaction Script, Table Model, Active Record and Domain driven design.

Comment: Arguably it depends on what you really want to achieve. As @Crowcoder mentioned above, you might be able to get away with just one set of models, because you need to answer:
1. How many people will work on the code?
2. How many classes are there?
3. How big is the app?
4. What is the purpose of the app?

Then you can decide for yourself whether this business layer/DAL separation even makes sense for you. Those techniques are usually aimed at limiting the scope of any future/probable changes